# How to change JavaScript bundle directory path from assets to internal storage in React Native AAR in Android?

Tags: android, react-native

We are using React Native with our existing application.

Due to various reasons, we are downloading a JavaScript bundle from our server and storing it in internal storage.

Now we want React Native AAR to refer to our JavaScript bundle **from internal storage instead of the assets folder**. For this, somewhere we will need to **set a JavaScript bundle directory path**, that React Native refers to.

Please let me know how we can achieve this. Is there some kind of property where this path can be set?

Comment: Have you tried adding it to your settings.gradle? 
include ':YourCustomSDK'
project('YourCustomSDK').projectDir = new File('../somecustompath')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my question after a little research.
In Android, to start react application we need an instance of `ReactInstanceManager`. `ReactInstanceManagerBuilder` is an builder class for `ReactInstanceManager`. `ReactInstanceManagerBuilder` has method to set path to JS bundle file. 
Please refer below snippet.

```
ReactInstanceManagerBuilder builder = ReactInstanceManager.builder();
builder.setJSBundleFile("PATH TO YOUR JSBundleFile"); // ex: "assets://index.android.js" or "/sdcard/main.jsbundle"
.
.//other setter calls
.
mReactInstanceManager = builder.build();
mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, appName, arguments);
```

Answer (score 2):

On android, the bundle file is provided by the `ReactNativeHost`.
To provide a custom file, you should:

1. Subclass `ReactNativeHost`. The default react native template already does that for you inside MainApplication (the `mReactNativeHost` member is an anonymous subclass)
2. Override `getJSBundleFile` with a URI to your file (in internal storage)
3. Override `getReactNativeHost` in `MainApplication` and return your custom host implementation.

Example:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.asList(new MainReactPackage());
    }

    @Override protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }

    @Nullable @Override protected String getJSBundleFile() {
      return "uri://to/your/file"; // <----!!
    }
  };

  @Override public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```